# PHP json_encode() specific key of an array

Tags: php, json

I am using `PHP 5.5.12`.

**I have an array like:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [medicine_id] => 1
            [time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [event_type] => before_breakfast
                            [time] => 07:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [event_type] => after_breakfast
                            [time] => 07:30:00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [medicine_id] => 2
            [time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [event_type] => before_lunch
                            [time] => 13:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [event_type] => after_lunch
                            [time] => 14:00:00
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [medicine_id] => 3
            [time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [event_type] => before_dinner
                            [time] => 20:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [event_type] => after_lunch
                            [time] => 21:00:00
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want to `json_encode()` the field `time` of each root level.

**I tried using:**

```
foreach ($user_medicine_times as $user_medicine_key => $user_medicine_value) {
    $user_medicine_value['time'] = json_encode($user_medicine_value['time'], true);
}
```

**and:**

```
foreach ($user_medicine_times as $user_medicine_key => &$user_medicine_value) {
    $user_medicine_value['time'] = json_encode($user_medicine_value['time'], true);
}
```

But using `print_r($user_medicine_value)`, it returns the same array.

**I want the result to be as follows:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [medicine_id] => 1
            [time] => "[{"event_type":"before_breakfast","time":"07:00:00"},{"event_type":"after_breakfast","time":"07:30:00"}]"

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [medicine_id] => 2
            [time] => "[{"event_type":"before_lunch","time":"13:00:00"},{"event_type":"after_lunch","time":"17:00:00"}]"

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [medicine_id] => 3
            [time] => "[{"event_type":"before_dinner","time":"20:00:00"},{"event_type":"after_lunch","time":"17:00:00"}]"

        )

)
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: You've asked a similar question today and apparently deleted that question, why ?! We have bounty's if you think your question didn't receive enough attention.

Comment: Its better to make a new array consisting only the values of `[time]` and then use `json_encode`

Comment: The question I deleted was to something related to filter an array and replace specific key value, I've achieved it. This is regarding convert specific key value to JSON. Bounties are eligible after 2 days. I cannot wait for that long if working on deadline. Also, without providing existing solution, down vote is arrogance I think that I've deleted it.

Comment: 2nd variant shold work

Comment: @Dev its an array of object not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your question earlier and prepared the answer but you removed it before i paste the answer. Anyways here is the solution

```
function outer(&$val, $key) {
    $val['time'] = json_encode($val['time']);
}
array_walk($your_array, 'outer');
print_r($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, in every iteration, the value is not being saved anywhere,

You have two options here, either make new array having `time` key with `json_encode()` or pass the value by reference as shown below.

```
foreach ($user_medicine_times as $user_medicine_key => &$user_medicine_value) {
                                                       ^
    $user_medicine_value['time'] = json_encode($user_medicine_value['time'], true);
}
```

Comment: Because of &$user_medicine_value it gives error :  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). And using true in json_encode also not affecting the provided array. It returns the same array I've used as an input.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your foreach loop's content with something like this:

```
foreach ($user_medicine_times as $user_medicine_key => $user_medicine_value) {
    $user_medicine_times[$user_medicine_key]['time'] = json_encode($user_medicine_value['time'], true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the json encode fails because your time array contains an stdClass Object. Try to convert this like that :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($user_medicine_value['time'] as $value) {
    $result['event_type'] = $value->event_type;
    $result['time'] = $value->time;
}
$user_medicine_value['time'] = $result;
```